# struggling with syntax for the_post_thumbnail();

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails

i want to display the alt text for a featured image.

I've been using the the_post_thumbnail(); function to display the image

like this:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail('medium');
}
```

Question: How do I display the Alt attribute for this image?

Comment: To clarify, I want to display text under the image like a typical caption. In Fact, if I could get it to display a caption, that would be awesome.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/how-to-retrieve-an-image-attachments-alt-text

Answer (score 1):

[`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) accepts second parameter `$attr`, that's array of options, so to display alt for image use something like this:

```
 the_post_thumbnail( 'medium', array( 'alt' => 'Image alt' ) );
```

Comment: OK, that doesn't show the alt tag, it sets the alt tag to 'Image alt' ...it's still more than I had. TY for the help with array syntax :)

Comment: So you want display text under the images, right?

Comment: yes please. like a caption

Comment: This doesn't work anymore in WP 5.5

Answer (score 0):

something I tried a while ago - purely experimental, not widely tested - this will wrap the thumbnail and caption into a div similar to a wp-caption image:
(this filter function needs to be added to functions.php of your theme)

```
// 27/01/2012 alchymyth
// show thumbnail with caption, if it is entered, wrapped with <div class="wp-caption thumb-caption"> ;
// show just the thumbnail otherwise
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html','add_post_thumbnail_caption',10,5);
function add_post_thumbnail_caption($html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr) {        
if( $html == '' ) { return $html;
} else {
 $out = '';

  $thumbnail_image = get_posts(array('p' => $post_thumbnail_id, 'post_type' => 'attachment'));

  if ($thumbnail_image && isset($thumbnail_image[0])) {

  $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id, $size); 
  $t_width = $image[1] +0; // +0 here for no extra padding, needs to be considered in writing css - the default image caption uses +10;
  $class = $attr['class'];
    if($thumbnail_image[0]->post_excerpt) $out .= '<div class="wp-caption thumb-caption '.$class.'" style="width:'.$t_width.'px; ">';

    $out .= $html; 

    if($thumbnail_image[0]->post_excerpt) $out .= '<p class="wp-caption-text">'.$thumbnail_image[0]->post_excerpt.'</p></div>'; 
  }
return $out; 
}
/*css classes for this:
.wp-caption.thumb-caption { }
.wp-caption.thumb-caption img { }
.wp-caption.thumb-caption .wp-caption-text { }
*/
}
```

example output:

```
<div class="wp-caption thumb-caption " style="width:165px; "><img width="165" height="150" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/birthday_cake-180x163.jpg" class="attachment-580x150 wp-post-image" alt="happy birthday" title="birthday_cake" /><p class="wp-caption-text">happy birthday</p></div>
```

Comment: This looks impressive. Did you put the function in the functions.php or directly in single.php?

Comment: as a filter, I put that into functions.php of a theme.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using on my page.php

It's enclosed by php operators. I'm using css to format it.

It seems a little too simple. What am I missing?

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    echo '<div class="featured-image">';
    the_post_thumbnail('medium');
    echo '<span id="caption">' . get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id() )->post_excerpt . '</span>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: 'What am I missing?' does this mean it is not working as expected? (I just tried the code in single.php and it was working) have you added a caption under ***dashboard -> media -> library -> edit media*** for those images?

Comment: My CSS was incomplete at the time of the post. My apologies.