# Thumbnail informations (meta)

Tags: thumbnails

Does anyone know how can I display in the loop thumbnail's name, alternative text, title, caption, url?

Thx for all advices and suggestions

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Retrieve An Image Attachment's Alt Text?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/how-to-retrieve-an-image-attachments-alt-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code inside the loop and modify it as per requirement.

```
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
echo 'Name = '.  get_post_field( 'post_name', $thumb_id ).'<br />';
echo 'Alt = '.  get_post_meta( $thumb_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ).'<br />';
echo 'Title = '.  get_the_title( $thumb_id ).'<br />';
echo 'Caption = '.  get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $thumb_id ).'<br />';
echo 'Description = '.  get_post_field( 'post_content', $thumb_id ).'<br />';
echo 'SRC = '. wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb_id ).'<br />';
echo 'URL = '. get_permalink( $thumb_id ).'<br />';
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need thank you very much :)