# alt of attached image in post / pages

Tags: posts, post-meta

As stated here [How To Retrieve An Image Attachment's Alt Text?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/how-to-retrieve-an-image-attachments-alt-text)

"*Image's 'alt' text is stored as a string in wp_postmeta with the meta_key of '_wp_attachment_image_alt'*"

I am using below code to print alt tag of attached image...

```
<? get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Did you try to echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); as your code just returns it and not prints it.

Comment: @AhmedElmahdy yes. i tried that. i forgot to that mentioned because i tried many ways to sort it out. I also tried `<?php get_image_tag( $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size ); ?>`

Comment: Can you post please the full code scope where you have tried it and it didn't work?

Comment: @AhmedElmahdy please check '<a target="_blank" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="hover-img" style="height:235px; width: 100%;" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="<? echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>"></a>'

Comment: Below that code can you test printing $post->ID and tell me what you get? e.g. echo $post->ID;

Comment: it is 117 which is correct id of the post. @AhmedElmahdy

Comment: i have created a complete new theme from scratch. could that be an issue?? @AhmedElmahdy

Comment: Are you sure that 117 is the id of attachment and not the post?

Comment: Did you try get_post_thumbnail_id() instead of $post->ID

Comment: @AhmedElmahdy tried. not working. I don't understand this when $post->id is showing correct.

Comment: @AhmedElmahdy "Are you sure that 117 is the id of attachment and not the post?" Yes, 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get attached image title and alt.

```
//Get attachment title & alt...
$attachment_title = '';
$attachment_alt = '';

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => 1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_mime_type' => 'image'); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);

//If attachments exist...
if($attachments) {

  //Loop until attachments...
  foreach( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    $attachment_title = $attachment->post_title;
    $attachment_alt = get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
  }
}
```

Hope this hope you well!