# Theme logo metadata into template file

Tags: theme-development, images, theme-customizer, get-theme-mod

I'm looking to pull all of the metadata (e.g. alt, width, height) from the theme logo, which is uploaded through Appearance -> Customization into my theme template file. This is what I currently have, but it's not working:

```
$custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod('custom_logo');
if ($custom_logo_id) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($custom_logo_id, 'full');
    $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($custom_logo_id);
    echo '<img src="' . $image[0] . '" alt="' . $meta['alt'] . ' width="' . $meta['width'] . '" height="' . $meta['height'] . '">';
} else {
    echo bloginfo('name');
}
```

Comment: That looks like it should work. What is the problem with the output you get?

Comment: I get the width and the height but it's not pulling the alt metadata: Notice: Undefined index: alt in C:\xampp\htdocs\vistex-foundation\wp-content\themes\brandozz\header.php on line 28
 width=

Comment: Perhaps because no al-text was defined when the image was uploaded?

Comment: No, I checked that...it is defined

Comment: Ah, wait I remember something about this. I'll get back to you shortly.

Comment: Is alt not stored in wp_get_attachment_metadata? Looking at the Codex, I don't believe that it is: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata

Comment: yeah that's the problem

Answer (score 1):

Ends up that "alt" is not stored in wp_get_attachment_metadata so I pulled it from the post meta:

```
$custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod('custom_logo');
if ($custom_logo_id) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($custom_logo_id, 'full');
    $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($custom_logo_id);
    **$alt_text = get_post_meta($custom_logo_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);**
    echo '<img src="' . $image[0] . '" alt="' . $alt_text . '" width="' . $meta['width'] . '" height="' . $meta['height'] . '">';
} else {
    echo bloginfo('name');
}
```

Comment: I added the $alt_text variable which pulls it from get_post_meta

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the description of [`wp_get_attachment_metadata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata) there's no alt field stored in that location. The easiest way out would be to just use the title-field for the alt.

Otherwise you can retrieve the alt-field using [`get_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/). More explanation [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/how-to-retrieve-an-image-attachments-alt-text).